# how to write a react-native button with firebase auth

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

I'm having some difficulty to wrap my head around async functions and firebase auth. I have the login function in another file as:

```
async function loginWithEmail(email, password) {
  firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
}
```

and the button as :

```
 <TouchableOpacity
      style={style.button}
      onPress={() => {
        loginWithEmail(email, password)
          .then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
            navigation.navigate("Home");
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          });
      }}
    >
      <Text style={style.buttonText}>LOGIN</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

But I keep getting error: TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

How do I do this properly? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Write `loginWithEmail` function like this

```
const loginWithEmail = async (email, password) => {
  const response = await firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

  console.log(response);
  // Do operation such as navigation etc here..
  return response;
};
```

And the Button like this

```
<TouchableOpacity
  style={style.button}
  onPress={() => loginWithEmail(email, password)}
>
  <Text style={style.buttonText}>LOGIN</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>;
```

Comment: your function doesn't return , hence add this line at the end of the "loginWithEmail" function:   "return response"